# How to make file upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i'm using codeigniter,I want make file upload functionality in codeigniter,i already wrote code but it's accepting all type of files it's not showing error massage also.

this is my view page HTML code:file name is:welcome_message.php

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type = "file" name = "userprofile" size = "20" required="">
        </div>
```

This is my controller code:file name is:Welcome.php

```
       public function index()  
    {   
         $this->load->view('welcome_message', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('Welcome', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userprofile'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->Welcome->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->Welcome->data());

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
```

my success message file: file name :upload_success.php:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
<li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<p><?php echo anchor('Welcome', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your form element?

Comment: First tell what kind of files you want to upload. You can restrict the files on html side as well using accept="image/*" then after that the configuration of upload file will help.

Comment: I need accept this type of  $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';

Comment: @raja have  you checked my answer again

Comment: You don't have form tags in view I see use form helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Answer (score 0):

you need to change from this

```
                $error = array('error' => $this->Welcome->display_errors();
```

to this

```
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors();
```

same here when you dont have any error

```
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->Welcome->data());
```

to

```
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
```

you need to echo the error to display it.
check this now

```
  public function index()  
    {   
         $this->load->view('welcome_message', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('Welcome', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('my_n_file')) //just use your name here
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
```

view file to display error

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Upload Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
   <form >
<input type="file" name="my_n_file"> // just use your name here
<?=isset($error)?$error:"";?>
<button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I changed like that but same , not show that error all type of file is taking.

Comment: @raja check this now

Comment: @raja the view is different . its the view where you have your form

Answer (score 0):

You have not include the variable where the error will display. You have to add

```
<?php echo $error;?>
```

Also check the files in html also using

```
accept="image/*"
```

Hope this helps!